# I get an error while running [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-bluetooth, objective-c++

I decided to deal with Bluetooth on IOS and immediately got an error that I can not understand and can not find solutions on the Internet.

By commenting on the code, I realized that the error is caused by this line: "centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];"

**BT.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface BT : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
{
    CBCentralManager *centralManager;
    CBPeripheral *discoveredPeripheral;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@end
```

**BT.mm:**

```
#import "BT.h"

@implementation BT


-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I get the following compiler error: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

If you comment out the line "centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];", the project will compile without errors.

**UPDATE:**

I realized that if you remove armv7 from "Build Settings" -> "Valid Architecture", the error disappears, but there is another error. I think that it is impractical to remove the architecture of armv7, so we need to understand where the first error occurs.

**Problem Solved**

You must add "CoreBluetooth.framework" in the project.

Comment: What's the linker error? Make sure your are linking the `CoreBluetooth` framework.

Comment: @rmaddy How can I be sure of that? (I'm new to xcode)

Comment: @rmaddy You were right, I should have added a framework, thank you very much!